# What is an accepted equivalent of non-parametric version two-way ANOVA in R package?

Tags: r, anova, two-way

I use R for my statistical analysis.

I want to analyse a kinetics experiment that involves measurement over 3 time points with control, genetic background 1, 2 and 3.

Can anyone suggest a test and how to arrange the data for that particular test?

I would also need to do individual comparisons between time, group and time:group.

Comment: Questions that are just about how to use R / requests for code / packages, etc. are generally off topic here. The statistical aspects of this are covered in the linked thread.

Answer (score 3):

There is an R package called "The Pairwise Multiple Comparison of Mean
Ranks Package (PMCMR)" which provides several nonparametric tests (which goes beyond the limitation of the Kruskal-Wallis test which cannot be applied for factorial ANOVA) [Here is the link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOwuXnr67TAhXCNo8KHX3iAgcQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2FPMCMR%2Fvignettes%2FPMCMR.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH__-tv6KbR2BDUtiz_-Veny1zcGQ)

Wilcox's robust statistics functions (WRS2 package in R). You can find a lot of functions for robust tests described in in Rand Wilcox's book "Introduction to Robust Estimation and Hypothesis Testing". This can also be used to test the interaction in factorial designs. [Here is the link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQta3_r67TAhUGto8KHe4UAmoQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2FWRS2%2FWRS2.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG1o_cWaB1dyG_C882R-y2fMS_n4g)

For a detailed reading, you may follow [this](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2016-1/feys.pdf) link.

Comment: as it currently stands, this answer is a little bit too short, and runs the risk of being deleted. Please add some explanation

Comment: @Antoine Explanations have been added with links to follow.